# Providers for same InjectionToken in multiple modules with different classes

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular6

I have a `BaseComponent` that needs to be injected with either `Service_A` or `Service_B` using an `InjectionToken`:

```ts
export const SERVICE_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Service_A | Service_B>('ServiceInjector');

...

export class BaseComponent {
   constructor(
     @Inject(SERVICE_TOKEN)
     public service: Service_A | Service_B
   ) { }
}
```

There are two components which extend `BaseComponent`: `Component_A` and `Component_B`.
For each of them I want to inject their corresponding service.

This works fine if I use DI provider at component level:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-component-a',
  templateUrl: `../base.component.html`,
  providers: [{
    provide: SERVICE_TOKEN,
    useClass: Service_A
  }]
})
export class Component_A extends BaseComponent { }
```

```ts
@Component({
   selector: 'ui-component-b',
   templateUrl: `../base.component.html`,
   providers: [{
     provide: SERVICE_TOKEN,
     useClass: Service_B
   }]
})
export class Component_B extends BaseComponent { }
```

However, if I put `Component_A` and `Component_B` into their own modules and use dependency providers at module level, both components end up being injected with the same service:

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: SERVICE_TOKEN,
    useClass: Service_A
  }],
  declarations: [
    Component_A
  ],
  exports: [
    Component_A
  ]
})
export class A_Module { }
```

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: SERVICE_TOKEN,
    useClass: Service_B
  }],
  declarations: [
    Component_B
  ],
  exports: [
    Component_B
  ]
})
export class B_Module { }
```

Is there a way to resolve the dependency in multiple modules with different classes using the same `InjectionToken`?

[Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx6p6u)